# How do I open a file using python to read and write? Ubuntu server

Tags: python

What I want to do is edit the etc/samba/smb.conf  and I want to add

```
[Test's Files]
 comment = Test's Files
 path = /files/test
 browsable = yes
 read only = no
 valid users = test
```

all of this via a Python web application that recieves information from the user's input. For now I just want to know how I would add that piece of text to the file with python.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `open()` function in python to obtain a file:

```
with open('path/to/file', 'w') as output_file:
   output_file.write('content')
```

The second parameter to the open command is the mode. More details can be found on [the Python documentation website](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open). Side note: if this is in /etc/, then your application may need special permissions to be able to write to this file. To limit the potential danger of elevated privileges, you should create a subprocess with the elevated permissions that does nothing but write this file so that your main process has normal permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into SMBCOnnection module in python.http://pythonhosted.org/pysmb/api/smb_SMBConnection.html

I have already worked with it is a great module to work with smb server.

with open('path to file', 'w') as fileobj:
   fileobj.write('text to be written')

the above peice of code is very hand to open, write.And close a file implicitly performing opening and closing operations

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in this simple way:

```
with open('/etc/whatever.txt', 'a+') as file:
    file.write("""[Test's Files]
comment = Test's Files
path = /files/test
browsable = yes
read only = no
valid users = test""")
```

But you need to pay attention to the permissions if you want to edit files that only root can write. Please, pay attention to the *mode* how you open the file! This **must** be **'a+'** and **NOT** 'w' as it is shown in other answers! Otherwise you will overwrite the file!